# Custom attribute data annotation

Tags: vb.net, oop

I would like to create a mapping key/value data annotation for my attributes, so that i will loop the entity class and read all the attribute key/vaue pair(column name & values) and pass to the stored procedure
For eg)
I need to create like below

```
  <Key:="Empl_Name",Value=mEmployeeName>
     Public Property EmployeeName() As String
        Get
            Return mEmployeeName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            mEmployeeName = Value
        End Set
     End Property
```

To achieve this, do i need to use ColumnAttribute class of system.Attribute or is there a better way to achieve? Iam using .net 4 Vb.net.Please suggest